# Include a unique URL in EXE

Tags: .net

I want to give users of my site the ability to upload their software/hardware configuration automatically on Windows. So I'm thinking of having an EXE file download, and somehow put in that EXE a unique URL for each user. When the data is collected, the program would just posts some JSON to that URL. How can I do it? I'm most familiar with .NET platform. Tools like this do exist, for example Blizzard uses this approach for their beta test enroll. Each user downloads a slightly different EXE.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? Which part of the operation are you unsure how to go about?

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a unique identifier for each user

`Guid.NewGuid()`

then either embed that into the download. Or much simpler: create the Guid the first time the user runs the application. Then a single download will be sufficient.

Comment: Then save it in a database on the server. One table including UserID and GUID (or just use the Guid as UserID). You can either create that the first time the user connects to your server (and supplies an yet-unknown Guid) or precreate it before downloading and include the Guid in the download (either by simply including a text file containing the Guid or by modifying the .exe).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple approaches that occur to me off the bat.

If you truly need a unique id embedded directly in the executable, then you are talking about:

1. Compiling a separate executable for each download, in which case you'll need to script out the act of changing some file used to build the exe, and calling csc.exe to compile a unique exe file for each user at the time of the download.
2. Locating the unique key embedded in the .exe file itself, and editing it in-place just before downloading the file.

Both of these seem a bit heavy-handed to me. Why can't you just keep the unique key in a separate file? As long as it's unique to each user, I don't see why it would need to be embedded directly into the exe. You'll still need a way to package it up for delivery, of course. You could zip up the "key file" with an installer, and script the installer to copy the key file to the location of the exe file, I suppose.

Of course, the identifier should be encrypted somehow to stop casual hackers from breaking your system, perhaps using the registered user's name as the initialization vector (IV) or salt value to the encryption routine. As long as the executable itself doesn't actually *use* the key for anything, then it won't even need to have the private key used to decrypt it. To the exe, it's just a magic value that it uses when asking for updates. The exe could pass this value in the querystring or post data of the request for updates. On your end, you decrypt the value, pull out the user ID, and use that to generate the new download if there is one.

If you want the executable to *use* the value, perhaps at startup to verify that it's a "genuine" copy, then you're going to have to give it the ability to decrypt the key. This means embedding the decryption key into the exe file, and hoping no-one digs it out with Reflector or something.

At this point, you're talking about full-fledged copy protection, in which case you're much better off finding a commercially available system than trying to write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Mel. I think I'll go with csc.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling an application with a unique string. You could search the resulting binary for that string at substitute it with another string of the same length.

I don't know if .NET uses checksums or anything though.